# how to shorten variables

Tags: php, variables

I have this

```
$terim1=$isaret1.$carpan1.$terim1;
$terim2=$isaret2.$carpan2.$terim2;
$terim3=$isaret3.$carpan3.$terim3;
```

I wnat to do like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    $terim$i=$isaret$i.$carpan$i.$terim$i;
}
```

Is it possible? Or is there any solution?

Comment: Please read how to create a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the missing information to your Post :) If you haven't read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet i recommend to do so :) Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: No, you don’t want this. What you want is to use some ***arrays!***

Comment: I can not use an array because I made fiction incorrectly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it into curly brackets:

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
    ${"terim".$i} = ${"isaret".$i} . ${"carpan".$i} . ${"terim".$i};
}
```

See it online: **https://eval.in/927730**

```
<?php

$isaret1 = 'aa';
$carpan1 = 'bb';
$terim1 = 'cc';
$isaret2 = 'AA';
$carpan2 = 'BB';
$terim2 = 'CC';
$isaret3 = '11';
$carpan3 = '22';
$terim3 = '33';
$terim1=$isaret1.$carpan1.$terim1;
$terim2=$isaret2.$carpan2.$terim2;
$terim3=$isaret3.$carpan3.$terim3;

for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
    ${"terim".$i} = ${"isaret".$i} . ${"carpan".$i} . ${"terim".$i};
}

echo PHP_EOL . $terim1;
echo PHP_EOL . $terim2;
echo PHP_EOL . $terim3;
```

will produce

> aabbaabbcc
>   AABBAABBCC
>   1122112233

Comment: Thanks! I also thing ino is right but now I must do it like that :( I will grow over time.

Comment: @biyro2 Good. Let other users know that the solution is OK by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually do this with var vars (like seen in other answers). The better way should actually be to use arrays instead.

```
for($i = 0; $i<4; $i++){
    $terim[$i] = $isaret[$i] . $carpan[$i] . $terim[$i];
}
```

Doing it like this, you could also easy pass `$terim` easy to other functions without modifing everytime the whole signature. On top of this, you know exactly how much values you have inside the array and could replace the `4` with `count($terim)`.

To say it again - using var vars solves your current problem, but not the structural problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called a variable variable

```
$$a
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

e.g. for your case:

```
$testvar1=1;
$testvar2=2;
$testvar3=3;
$a='testvar';

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
echo ${$a.$i};
```

Comment: Thanks! It is usable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $var1 = 'retim' . $i;
    $var2 = 'isaret' . $i . 'carpan' . $i . 'terim' . $i;
    $$var1 = $$var2;
}
```